# Using the Factor Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

[image]

We are asked to use the above Theorem to show that:

$f(x)=x^{91} + 3x^{73} - 2x^{37} - 2$ has ($x-1$) as a factor.

It's easy to show that $f(1)=0$ by inserting $1$ for $x$, yielding:

$f(1)=1^{91} + 3(1)^{73} - 2(1)^{37} - 2=0$

Does it suffice to say that because $f(1)=0$, by the Factor Theorem, $(x-1)$ is a factor of $f(x)$?

Or do we need to establish that: $f(x)$ having $(x-1)$ as a factor $\Rightarrow$ $1$ is a root of $f(x)$ as well?

Comment: Nah.. what you have already proved is enough. The statement has an "if and only if"... so its a bi-implication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asked to show that $x-1$ is a factor of $f(x)$. The theorem tells you that this is equivalent to showing that $f(1) = 0$. So since you have shown that, you are done. There is nothing more to do.